# In a ring, does $a^2=0$ imply $a=0$?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $a$ be an element of $R$: $a^2 = 0$. Must it be true that $a = 0$? (Assuming $0$ is the additive identity of $R$)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent

Comment: Hello: I took a moment to make your title useful. The title "additive identity of a ring" was very unuseful considering the question you asked. Quite often, the question itself can be used as a good title.  Please try something like this in the future.  Although, be aware that the question still should appear in the body, even if it appears in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ we have $2^2=0$, yet $2\neq0$.

Comment: I think you mean ${\bf Z}/4{\bf Z}$.  The field with 4 elements is by definition an integral domain.

Comment: Of course, thank you.

Comment: I see now... thanks!